# How can I disable href of anchor in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-pagination

I am using multiple pagination in single web page. here I am using jquery-ajax for pagination. but even if I am keeping "base_url" option as blank I am unable to hold redirection of anchor.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 2;
$config['anchor_class'] = "onclick='return show_new_page();'";
```

Comment: try `$config['base_url'] = '#'`;

Comment: Can you explain what is your issue?

Comment: Issue with base url or pagination?

Comment: use Codeigniter Pagination

Comment: @KevalRathi I want to call every page with ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would create a custom library
[(read about it here)](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Go the */system/libraries* and copy *pagination.php* file from here to the */application/libraries*

Rename it to something you like. Open it, find *create_links* function, find anchors, edit it the way you want.
Load your custom pagination into your controller's function.

Also, don't forget to change the class name of the library to the name of the file.